# fn key always on when plugged to electricity

Tags: windows-8, fn-key

I use a Samsung laptop with windows 8. When not plugged to electric, keyboard is just fine. Iif i want to raise the volume I press <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>.
Otherwise keyboard acts like fn is on and pressing fn does not change anything, for example pressing fn and F5 does not reload page but just turns off touchpad.

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS settings? Perhaps there is something in there about that... Press and hold either F12 or F2 (Without the Fn key) while starting up to enter the BIOS menu.